# Py2Neo - how to get around iterating the record object returned from cypher queries to access the query data

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I use py2neo to connect to Neo4j.

E.g I have a query that gives this result (I can actually be anything: numbers, strings....)

```
number      |   first name   | last name
--------------------------------------
1           |   Anne         | Hathaway
2           |   Tom          | Cruise
3      ....
```

Whenever I execute the cypher query from python (using the graph.cypher.execute or graph.cypher.stream commands), I get a Record object returned and I need to iterate through the record object to access the individual elements to access them and store them in for example a numpy matrix.

Is there a way to have the result from a cypher query stored immediately in a list,numpy matrix,.... in python?

Basically: how can I skip the record object that gets returned and avoid unnecessary manipulations to prepare the data for further calculations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you get back from `cypher.execute()` is a `RecordList` containing `Record` objects.

Both `RecordList` and `Record` behave like iterables, i.e. you can iterate with `for x in recordlist` through all records and with `for x in record` through all return values of a single record.

`ResultList` has an attribute `records` which returns the list of `Record` objects. You can pass this to any constructor that accepts a list of lists, such as Pandas DataFrame or numpy matrix:

```
import py2neo
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

result = graph.cypher.execute(myquery)

# Pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(result.records, columns=result.columns)

# numpy matrix
matrix = np.matrix(result.records)
```

This works of course only if you return data types which can be stored in a DataFrame or matrix.

Comment: So simple! I love it.